# What is the Roman Catholic Church's position on the Eastern Orthodox Church?

Tags: catholicism, church-history, eastern-orthodox, ecclesiology

What is the official Roman Catholic position on the Eastern (Greek) Orthodox Church? Obviously, there was a mutual anathema/ex-communication declared between them a long time ago - has it been updated formally?

Does the Roman Catholic church validate sacramental rites administered by an Orthodox priest?
Do Roman catholic theologians consider Greek Orthodox clergy or practitioners as Christians, and would they treat them as being 'in communion with the body of Christ'? Or do they have to submit to some form of romanization to be 'restored to fellowship'?

Comment: I'd have to check for specifics in Cathehism and Canon Law, but in general Catholic Church believes that Eastern Orthodox Church keeps apostolic succession, so sacraments received within this Church are valid. According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/East%E2%80%93West_Schism), anathemas were revoked in 1965. There's a [semi-related question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/56277/44912) about possibility for whole church to join CC.

Comment: Most Catholic missals I’ve seen invite Orthodox Christians to receive the Eucharist. The Orthodox do not reciprocate this.